# Why "typeof SVGElement.prototype.getBBox" is "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using `.getBBox()` in code and it is working fine, but when I try

```
typeof SVGElement.prototype.getBBox
```

It returns `"undefined"`.
why is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because getBBox is not defined on all SVG elements, it's only defined on elements that implement the [SVGLocatable](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) interface.

Comment: Then why `.getBBox()` is working if `typeof SVGElement.prototype.getBBox` not implemented?

Comment: I am using `.getBBox()` for `tspan`.

Comment: Because descendants of SVGElements such as tspan elements do implement SVGLocatable.